# What is the difference between a normal executable jar vs building jar using izpack

Tags: izpack

What is the difference between a normal executable jar vs building jar using izpack ?

a) Does it have pre-build configurable wizards?
b) Advantages over the traditional executable jars?

I have build executable jars via eclipse, intellij and it works perfectly in any OS and it is platform independent as well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the first line on their official site says...

**Easily make installers that work seamlessly on Microsoft Windows™, Linux™, Solaris™ and Mac OS X™.**

http://izpack.org/